# Oracle 11.2.0.1 (32-bit) gives ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact while creating DB with dbca

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, centos7, oracle11gr2

I have installed `Oracle database 11.2.0.1 (32-bit)` on `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810`.
When I try to create the DB using dbca in silent mode, I get `ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact` error.
Here is the log:

```
Copying database files
DBCA_PROGRESS : 1%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 2%
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

DBCA_PROGRESS : 4%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 37%
Creating and starting Oracle instance
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

DBCA_PROGRESS : 38%
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

DBCA_PROGRESS : 40%
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

DBCA_PROGRESS : 45%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 50%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 51%
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

DBCA_PROGRESS : 56%
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

DBCA_PROGRESS : 57%
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

DBCA_PROGRESS : 61%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 62%
Completing Database Creation
DBCA_PROGRESS : 66%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 70%
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

DBCA_PROGRESS : 73%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 74%
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

DBCA_PROGRESS : 85%
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

DBCA_PROGRESS : 86%
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

DBCA_PROGRESS : 98%
DBCA_PROGRESS : 100%
Database creation complete. For details check the logfiles at:
```

PS: I don't get any dbca issue with Oracle 11.2.0.4 (64-bit) but one of our applications needs oracle 32-bit and this one was the only one I could find and download from Oracle website.

Does anyone has any idea, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Only Oracle 11.2.0.4 support RHEL/CentOS 7.

Comment: Yeah, you're way out of support territory there, but try using dbca to generate the scripts, and then run them manually via SQL Plus.  Also check edelivery.oracle.com - there might be more versions of software there

Comment: How can an application require 32-bit database?